# pcap_set_rfmon does not work?

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap

I am trying to set my device to monitor mode, and i know its capable of being in monitor mode doing a "iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor" works, i run my code and i can capture packets from anywhere.

The problem is that in libpcap it fails to set my device to monitor mode at all(without entering the above-mentioned command line).I can't capture any packets until i manually connect to a access point.

```
       pcap_t *handler = pcap_create("wlan0",errbuff);
       if(pcap_set_rfmon(handler,1)==0 )
       {
           std::cout << "monitor mode enabled" << std::endl;
       }
       handler=pcap_open_live ("wlan0", 2048,0,512,errbuff);
       int status = pcap_activate(handler); //it returns 0 here.
```

so is this a code problem, or the pcap library problem?Anybody successfully set their device to monitor mode without using command lines?I am using a Realtek2500 btw.

Answer (score 11):

You're not supposed to use `pcap_open_live` *and* `pcap_create`/`pcap_activate` in the same code.  Try doing

```
pcap_t *handler = pcap_create("wlan0",errbuff);
if (handler == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "pcap_create failed: " << errbuf << std::endl;
    return; // or exit or return an error code or something
}
if(pcap_set_rfmon(handler,1)==0 )
{
    std::cout << "monitor mode enabled" << std::endl;
}
pcap_set_snaplen(handler, 2048);  // Set the snapshot length to 2048
pcap_set_promisc(handler, 0); // Turn promiscuous mode off
pcap_set_timeout(handler, 512); // Set the timeout to 512 milliseconds
int status = pcap_activate(handler);
```

and, of course, check the value of `status`.

Answer (score 0):

in addtion to Guy Harris's answer.
using **pcap_open_live** to open your device will make it been activated. you will get **PCAP_ERROR_ACTIVATED** -4, , when you continue to call **pcap_set_rfmon**.

```
/* the operation can't be performed on already activated captures */    
#define     PCAP_ERROR_ACTIVATED   -4
```

so use **pcap_create** to open the handle, and set rfmon, and call **pcap_activate** to activate it.

Comment: That's because, in response to this question, I added a check in `pcap_open_live()` to fail in that case; when the original poster asked the question, that check wasn't made.

Answer (score 0):

caution: pcap_set_rfmon() returns 0 on success...
so this code is correct:

```
   pcap_t *handler = pcap_create("wlan0",errbuff);
   **if(pcap_set_rfmon(handler,1) )**
   {
       std::cout << "monitor mode enabled" << std::endl;
   }
```