# capturing IEEE 802.11 packets without connecting to the network

Tags: wireshark, libpcap, packet-sniffers, wifi

> I want to analyze networks traffic but not by connecting it Just
>   switch on wifi and sniff the packets (IEEE 802.11 Frames)
>   in promiscuous mode

I have tried libpcap but it may be internally changing datalinktype as i am giving wifi interface in

```
descr=pcap_open_live("en1", MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 1, 512, errbuf);
```

(as we know mac OS x have en1 as wifi interface )

now when i do this

```
printf("%s", pcap_datalink_val_to_name( pcap_datalink(descr)));
```

It gives me result `"ethernet"`
I have tried to capture packets using wireshark without connecting to my wifi network and it worked!! 
I was able to capture `Beacon , Acknowledgement and Authentication frames` without connecting to my wifi network.

now:

1. do I have to make a network card driver for that or libpcap can do that ?if yes how?
2. Is wireshark making some kind of driver for that? if yes please help me to locate that  in it's source code.

   - I have tried Apple's CFNetwork but it too can't capture without connecting to the network.
   - It will be very helpful if i get some suggestion on some user space code as kernel level coding is a little tuff :(

I am coding on MacOS 10.7 in xCode 4.5.1

Update:
I am already doing this:

```
descr=pcap_create("e1", errbuf);
pcap_set_rfmon(descr, 0);
pcap_set_promisc(descr, 0);
pcap_activate(descr);    
descr=pcap_open_live("en1", 2048, 1, 512, errbuf);
```

> And yes there is a little monitor icon at the wifi and I can sniff the
>   packets but only when I connect to the network, I want to do the same
>   when I am not connected to wifi like capturing Beacon and
>   Acknowledgment Frames means packets through which our network card detects available wifi network

Comment: Got My Answer   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516436/pcap-set-rfmon-does-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on Snow Leopard or later (which you are, as you're running Lion), you should use the new `pcap_create()`/`pcap_activate()` APIs, and turn on monitor mode by calling `pcap_set_rfmon()` between the `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` calls.

That's what Wireshark 1.6.0 and later do if you check the monitor mode checkbox, and what tcpdump 1.0.0 and later, and TShark and dumpcap in Wireshark 1.6.0 and later, do if you specify the `-I` command-line flag.

By default, Wi-Fi interfaces on many OSes, including but not limited to OS X, supply Ethernet headers, not 802.11 headers, which is why `pcap_datalink_val_to_name(pcap_datalink(descr))` is reporting Ethernet headers.  On Linux and OS X, you have to go into monitor mode to get 802.11 headers; on *BSD, you can get 802.11 headers without going into monitor mode.

You do not need your own driver to go into monitor mode on OS X; Wireshark does not supply its own drivers.

Comment: Yes I was already in the monitor mode and able to sniff the packets but how to do that without connecting to the wifi ,like when you click the wifi icon you get the list of wifi available the packets that are received at that time is what I want to capture

Comment: Monitor mode should work regardless of whether you're connected to ("associated with") an 802.11 network or not.  However, going into monitor mode will not necessarily automatically *disconnect* you from the 802.11 network - it doesn't do so on most Macs running OS X.